Eddy currents caused by wind pollinated angiosperms to aid in pollination
dear biologists i hope everything is going well
as today i was reading angiosperm reporduction in my book campbell i came across a line
Wind tunnel studies
reveal that wind pollination is often
more efficient than it appears because
floral structures can create eddy
currents that aid in pollen capture. if some of you biologists do not know what eddy currents they are they are a topic of electromagnetic induction they are caused by changing magnetic fields which cause electric currents i could not find any research on this so if you all could please help me.

Most textbooks have a bibliography for their sources, usually broken up by chapter. Does Campbell? I'd also double check whether the book is talking about eddy currents in the electromagnetic sense, or whether they just mean eddies in the fluid dynamics sense. The later seems much more likely to me. (Though there is some cool research on pollinators using the electromagnetic fields around flowers).

Please take the trouble to divide your question into sentences starting with a capital letter and ending in a period/full stop. And as a new user finish reading the [Tour].
